# Rails: Object destroy performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app. I have my base model - User. There are lot of associated objects to the user.

```
Class User 
 has_many :contents, dependent: destroy
 has_many :messages, dependent: destroy
 has_many :ratings, dependent: destroy
 has_many :groups, dependent: destroy
 ...
end
```

When I want to remove user from my system (destroy user object), it takes about a minute to destroy all its associated objects. What is the best way to handle such cases?

One way that comes to my mind is:

Destroying in delayed_job:

But till the point user object gets destroyed in delayed job, this user should not be visible for others. Handle this case by having a flag say - deleted in user model and not fetching in results. But I use sphinx as well, and needs to make sure this user does not come up in sphinx results as well.

Is there a better way to handle such cases?

Comment: One option is to destroy the user first and delegate the destruction of related objects to delayed job.

Comment: Have you considered using `delete` instead of `destroy`? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @gabrielhilal yes. but in case of delete, the observer callbacks will not happen and I will have to do them as well manually. Like destroying user destroys groups which in turn has to update count and remove activities in group. Handling them separately makes code bit complex. But is that the way?

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is that, as you probably already know, the `.destroy` method will load each of the children objects and then call their `.destroy` methods.

The value in this is that any callbacks on the children are evaluated before doing the final destroy. So if a child needs to clear up anything elsewhere then it will do so. Also if the dependent objects throw an error during the destroy method, the entire destroy operation will rollback and you won't end up with some half-dead object limping around.

`.delete` will destroy the objects without loading them into memory or performing their callbacks. However (obviously) it won't perform their callbacks.

If you want to speed things up you could either simply do `dependent: :delete` as Octopus-Paul suggests. This will be fine however it won't destroy dependents on those objects, so for instance if groups had messages associated with them or perhaps ratings had comments associated with them, none of those will be destroyed.

To ensure that all downstream dependents get destroyed and any necessary callbacks are honoured I think the best you can do is to write a custom `before_destroy` method which does all clearing up but uses `.delete` and `.delete_all` in order to speed things up.

This will create legacy issues in that someone writing code downstream won't necessarily anticipate your method however you can judge the risk of that. The alternative (as you say) is to use a flag and do the job asynchronously. I'd imagine that this has fewer risks in the future but may be more expensive to implement today.

Answer (score 0):

:dependent

Controls what happens to the associated object when its owner is destroyed:

```
:destroy causes the associated object to also be destroyed
:delete causes the associated object to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not execute)
```

Delete will be much faster because it will simply run a database query for each association of the deleted user.

Find more options here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one-dependent

Comment: Thanks @Octopus-Paul. But my associated objects in turn has associations of its own. Like group has many activities. so destroying group has to destroy its associations.

Comment: In this case you cannot use :delete :D